# OpenACC constant parameters

Tags: openacc

I am wondering what is the proper way to handle constants in OpenACC kernels.

For example, in the following code

```
module vecaddmod

  implicit none

  integer, parameter :: n = 100000
  !$acc declare create(n)

contains
  subroutine vecaddgpu(r, a, b)
    real, dimension(:) :: r, a, b
    integer :: i
    !$acc update self(n)
    !$acc data present(n)
    !$acc kernels loop copyin(a(1:n),b(1:n)) copyout(r(1:n))
    do i = 1, n
       r(i) = a(i) + b(i)
    enddo
    !$acc end data
  end subroutine vecaddgpu
end module vecaddmod

program main
  use vecaddmod
  implicit none
  integer :: i, errs, argcount
  real, dimension(:), allocatable :: a, b, r, e
  character*10 :: arg1

  allocate( a(n), b(n), r(n), e(n) )
  do i = 1, n
     a(i) = i
     b(i) = 1000*i
  enddo
  ! compute on the GPU
  call vecaddgpu( r, a, b )
  ! compute on the host to compare
  do i = 1, n
     e(i) = a(i) + b(i)
  enddo
  ! compare results
  errs = 0
  do i = 1, n
     if( r(i) /= e(i) )then
        errs = errs + 1
     endif
  enddo
  print *, errs, ' errors found'
  if( errs ) call exit(errs)
end program main
```

`n` is declared as a constant on CPU in a module, and it is used as the range in the loop. `nvfortran` warns me about `Constant or Parameter used in data clause`. Is the above example the proper way to handle this? Can I take advantage of the constant memory on GPU, such that I don't need to copy it from CPU to GPU for each kernel launch?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The compiler will replace parameters with the literal value so no need to put them in data regions.

```
module vecaddmod

  implicit none

  integer, parameter :: n = 100000

contains
  subroutine vecaddgpu(r, a, b)
    real, dimension(:) :: r, a, b
    integer :: i
    !$acc kernels loop copyin(a(1:n),b(1:n)) copyout(r(1:n))
    do i = 1, n
       r(i) = a(i) + b(i)
    enddo
  end subroutine vecaddgpu
end module vecaddmod
```

...

```
% nvfortran -acc -Minfo=accel test.f90
vecaddgpu:
     11, Generating copyin(a(:100000)) << "n" is replaced with 100000
         Generating copyout(r(:100000)) 
         Generating copyin(b(:100000)) 
     12, Loop is parallelizable
         Generating Tesla code
         12, !$acc loop gang, vector(128) ! blockidx%x threadidx%x
```